# Stop Apps Script from creating GCP projects

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm seeing a large number of GCP projects being created by *serviceAccount:appsdev-apps-dev-script-auth@system.gserviceaccount.com*, following invocation of Apps Scripts.
I'd like to control or block such project creation.

What are the right ways to accomplish that?

Comment: Is this for a G Suite account, or paid Google account?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not possible. Quoting GCP Projects's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects):

> By default GCP projects have an Identity and Access Management (IAM)
>   policy with one entry, a Google service account that acts as the owner
>   of the default project. The Google service account is
>   **appsdev-apps-dev-script-auth@system.gserviceaccount.com**.

Also:

> Every Apps Script project uses the Google Cloud Platform to manage
>   authorization, Advanced services, and other details. To configure and
>   manage these settings, every Apps Script project has an associated
>   Google Cloud Platform project (a GCP project).

---

You can use a [default GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#default_cloud_platform_projects) or a [standard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#standard_cloud_platform_projects) project created by you, but the Apps Script project does need a GCP Project.

---

Moreover, since April 8, 2019 **it's not possible to access the default GCP projects** created for Apps Script projects unless they are older.

Comment: It's surprising that there is no "off" switch that prevents Apps Script from creating GCP projects, or even generally disables Apps Scripts from executing. I submitted this as a feature request.

Comment: You can rename or delete the folder hierarchy in GCP Console which appears something like Organization root > system-gsuite > apps-script. IF you rename it, users in the organization will not be able to create new Apps Script Project with Default GCP projects. If you delete that folder, even the Older Apps Script project will stop working. To make it work again, you will have to change the project to a standard GCP Project

Answer (score 0):

Best way to tackle this is to:

`gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)" --sort-by=projectId --filter='Generate AppScript v001' > GenerateAppScriptIDs.txt`

I made a script which is pretty neat for history, auditing etc [here](https://github.com/GangGreenTemperTatum/gcloudsdk/blob/main/commands_n_scripts/IAM/tidy_up_gcp_app_scripts_projects.sh)

Once you have that information, is to perform a follow-up deletion of each project ID.

```
% for i in `cat GenerateAppScriptIDs.txt`; do gcloud projects describe ${i}; done`
```

```
% for i in `cat GenerateAppScriptIDs.txt`; do gcloud projects delete ${i}; done`
```